# Make vertical scrollbar in bootstrap navbar when there are many items

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4, navbar, react-bootstrap

I made a sidebar using bootstrap in a react app. The code is below:

```
import React from 'react';
import './style_sidebar.css';

export default class Sidebar2 extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <ul className="nav flex-column sidebar bg-dark">
                    <h3 className="text-warning mt-3 ml-2">Bootstrap Sidebar</h3>
                    <i className="fa fa-user-circle text-white mt-3 ml-5 pl-4 icon-user" style={{'fontSize': '5em'}}></i>
                    <h4 className="text-warning ml-3 mt-5">Components</h4>
                    <li className="nav-item">
                        <a className="nav-link text-light" href="#a"><i className="fa fa-table fa-lg"></i> Table<hr className="bg-warning" /></a>
                    </li>
                    <li className="nav-item">
                        <a className="nav-link text-light" href="#b"><i className="fa fa-bar-chart fa-lg"></i> Chart<hr className="bg-warning" /></a>
                    </li>
                    <li className="nav-item">
                        <a className="nav-link text-light" href="#c"><i className="fa fa-wpforms fa-lg"></i> Form Elements<hr className="bg-warning" /></a>
                    </li>
                    <li className="nav-item">
                        <a className="nav-link text-light" href="#c"><i className="fa fa-lemon-o fa-lg"></i> Coming Soon<hr className="bg-warning" /></a>
                    </li>
                    <li className="nav-item">
                        <a className="nav-link text-light" href="#c"><i className="fa fa-lemon-o fa-lg"></i> Coming Soon<hr className="bg-warning" /></a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

and the css part is:

```
.sidebar {
    width: max-content;
    height: 100vh;
    padding: 10px;
    position: fixed;
    z-index: -1;
}

.user-icon {
    border: 1px solid;
    border-radius: 40px;
}

/* @media (max-width: 767px) {
    .sidebar {
      width: 100%;
      height: max-content;
    }
} */

@media only screen and (max-width: 600px) {
    .sidebar {
        width: 100%;
        height: max-content;
    }

    h3 {
        align-self: center;
    }  

    .icon-user {
        align-self: center;
        margin-right: 100px;
    }
  }
```

Now when i add more items to `ul` the items gets added to the top of the page. So i used `overflow-y:scroll` to make a vertical scrollbar when there are more number of items. But instead of `y-axis` scrollbar, it comes horizontal scroll bar. Anyway to fix this?

Also i am unable to make it responsive. I tried using `media query` but since i am new to bootstrap, i am finding it difficult to do.

Also how to make toggle button for sidebar, when screen-size is small the sidebar should collapse. I think you understood what i am trying to say. I am using latest version of Bootstrap. How to do it?

Answer (score 2):

You can solve the scrolling issue with this flex-wrap property:

```
.sidebar {
width: max-content;
height: 100vh;
padding: 10px;
position: fixed;
z-index: -1;
-ms-flex-wrap: nowrap;
flex-wrap: nowrap;
overflow-y: auto;
```

}

For responsiveness, initially hide the sidebar and toggle it on click of the toggle button.

Comment: it did not work, i am still getting horizontal scroll bar instead of vertical scroll bar.

Comment: I have solved the scroll issue for desktop, take a look at it : https://codesandbox.io/s/charming-hill-34zev .

Comment: I had min-height: 100vh, changed it to height: 100vh & it is working as expected. Scroll will not appear if height is not setup explicitly for positioned items.  Good job @sakpal